# Use Variable for Control Name

Tags: c#, controls

I have created multiple List and want to use each individual List when I have a variable name.

For example:

```
 private List<string> listAlabama = new List<string>();
 private List<string> listTexas = new List<string>();


// fill Lists with values


//Call Method to assign state to correct list
AssignNameToList("Alabama");


private void AssignNameToList(string state)
{


// Assign variable to the correct List  e.g
sring tempFindList="list"+state;

//Use the right List

string tempVal=tempFindList[0]???

//  should be listAlabama


}
```

Below is the solution I came up with using a Dictionary

```
      var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
                dictionary.Add("Alabama", listAlabama);
                dictionary.Add("Texas", listTexas);

                switch (tempState)
                {
                    case "Alabama":

                        List<string> value = dictionary["Alabama"];
                        Console.WriteLine(value);

                        string[] tempArray = value[totalPopulationIdx].Split(',');
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a `Dictionary<string, List <T>>`?

Comment: you can use  var list = this.GetType().GetField(tempFindList).GetValue(this) as List<string>;
            string tempVal = list[0];